# kotlinx.android.synthetic not found when running gradle

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm using Kotlin Android Extensions.
My project gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
...
```

My app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'jacoco-android'
apply plugin: "kotlin-allopen"
...
```

Gradle version 4.6
Android Studio 3.1.2
Build #AI-173.4720617, built on April 14, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.13.4

When running everything through the IDE everything works, but when running through the console `gradle -p ~/source/android-app assembleDebug` suddenly the IDE marks any `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main...` as not being used and any views in code are marked as not found. **The build succeeds**

It used to work, one of the versions that I upgraded (Android studio, gradle, Kotlin plugin)  broke it. Any ideas on what to do next ?

Console output:

`19:46 $ gradle -p ~/source/android-app assembleDebug --console plain
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /Users/efimerdler-kravitz/source/android-app/app/google-services.json
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
:app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin
:app:kaptDebugKotlin
:app:compileDebugKotlin
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug
:app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug
:app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:packageDebug
:app:assembleDebug`

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild?

Comment: @JoaquimLey `gradle clean && gradle -p ~/source/android-app assembleDebug` does not help

Comment: Even weirder , when running through the gradle menu in Android Studio it works, no error what so ever, only the command line fails

Answer (score 0):

in Android Studio file -> Invalidate Caches/Restart... -> btn "invalidate and restart"

Comment: Thank you, this is the first thing I did, didn't help

Comment: am having the same issue, when i use "gradlew clean build" i loose kotlinx.android.synthetic